# iPhone dock adapter- is it essential?

Tags: iphone, ipod, dock

I have a 30pin dock clock radio I used with my 3GS with corresponding dock adapter. I just upgraded to a 4 (I know, I know- in the past right?). However, I am insistent on keeping my iPhone 4 in a case. As a consequence, it will not fit into the dock with a dock adapter.

Is the adapter essential? I haven't bothered using on with my iPod touch as it is light, but the iPhone is heavier. It stays upright and I imagine it would be okay, but do you think it would damage the phones dock over time? Has any one had any experience of this occurring, or have you used docks like this with no problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can go both ways. The "metal" part, which you use to connect the iPhone with can get damaged if you use it without the plastic adapter piece.
However, I've been using myself that same construction over 6 months now and everything is still fine.

My answer: If you dare to risk it, just try it :) But don't look sad if the metal bends.

Comment: True enough. I've used it without the adapter quite a bit. The #1 key is to support the iPhone when you push the home button, or even tap on the screen.

Comment: I'd rather the dock was damaged than the iphone.. It seems pretty sturdy and there is naturally some 'give' either way. I do know someone who has docked their 3GS in such a manner and I'd imagine that a lot of people do the same thing without a second thought.

Comment: @Vblank your iPhone won't damage by this. Only if the hit it with a baseball bat maybe. Assuming you won't do that, you could try my answer :) Works for me.

Comment: My experience has been that the dock connecter on the clock radio will eventually bend, but the iPhone should be fine. I've got one that I used with a 3GS (with the adapter) and with a 4S (without the adapter), and after about 1.5 years of docking the iPhone 4S nightly, the connector on the clock radio finally gave out. The iPhone is fine, however. As bassplayer7 said, support the iPhone when pushing any buttons -- being gentle with it will prolong the life of the dock.

Answer (score 0):

nothing will happen to it, ive ben useing numerus docks for so long now none of them has seen any damage becouse of this, granted im a careful person, so it all comes down to you!, the ONLY dock witch has become slightly unstable at the connecter is a fake iPad 1 cover that i use with my iPad 2, *extra space and the iPad weighs, 600g compared to your phone witch is only 140g

so now you have my opinion, practical use, and facts, the decision is however yours!
good luck!

Comment: Yes, I imagine if you are heavy handed and bang it about it would damage it. If it was a bit lighter I wouldn't be bothered too much. I may just plug my iphone straight into the wall- just a shame to not use the dock ;)

Comment: as i said, its all up to you, however ive been using 3 of my docks like that with no issue! / also, if your option is not to use the dock and it just ends up laying there you might as well use it :P

Comment: Yeah. I mean it wasn't expensive at all, about right for a standard clock radio let alone an iphone docking one so its not a huge loss. As a say, I'm 100% fine with the iPod touch being on it as its so light, I just fear for the iphone.. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: unless its really cheap and you feel it being loose! you'll most likely be fine!